# LayoutInflater not Updating the View Property

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am simply using LayoutInflater to get A View(Button) From a layout.xml file other then the activity_main.xml. but When I change the setText("") property of the button the button property does not updates.

I am checking if I can change the text property of the button element in the testlayout.xml But when I set the property of the Button in onCreate and when I check for that property in call that was not changed...

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.testlayout, null);
        Button btn = (Button)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.testbtn);
        btn.setText("Hello");
    }


    public void call(View v){

        Button btn  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testBtn);
        Toast.makeText(this, btn.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainBtn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="73dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="call"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**testlayout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whered o you add the infalted layout to the activity?

Comment: I am checking if i can change the text property of the button element in the testlayout.xml But when I set the property of the Button in onCreate and when I check for that property in call that was not changed...

Comment: but you won't see the button text change unless you add it to the activity

Comment: in call(View v)  function I am checking for change property..

Comment: follow vipul;s answer and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this linearlayout to your activity:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.testlayout, null);
    Button btn = (Button)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setText("Hello");

    RelativeLayout rl=findViewById(R.id.root);
    rl.addView(linearLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add testlayout.xml as a child to the activity view using ViewGroup.addView(View child) method. Currently you see the button from the first layout. What are  you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the other xml to your current view :-

```
    package com.example.testdynamicviews;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView); // Your custom view will be added in this layout

        TextView text = myView();
        text.setText("Rahul GuptaRahul GuptaRahul GuptaRahul GuptaRahul GuptaRahul GuptaRahul Gupta");
        main.addView(text); // You forgot to add this line

        Button button = myCustomButton();
        button.setText("Custom Button");
        main.addView(button);
    }

    public TextView myView(){
        View v;
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.textview, null);
        int width = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.testwidth)/ getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return (TextView) v;
    }

    public Button myCustomButton(){
        View v;
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.custombutton, null);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        int width = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.testwidth)/ getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        return (Button) v;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

textview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sgfiughbjkh"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/testsize"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:ellipsize="end" >

</TextView>
```

custombutton.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text="sgfiughbjkh"
    android:textSize="@dimen/testsize" />
```